# Why the Swift compiler is not able to infer generic type when opaque type is returned for conforming to the `Sequence` protocol

Tags: swift, generics, opaque-result-type

I have a Swift package with implementation of a LinkedList class. I want to make my LinkedList conforming to the `Sequence` protocol. For that `makeIterator` returns `LinkedListIterator` instance which is hidden behind opaque `IteratorProtocol` type like follows:

```swift
extension LinkedList: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> some IteratorProtocol {
        LinkedListIterator(head: head)
    }
}
```

With the opaque type as above, I have a compilation error when I want to use Sequence features such as `map`:

```swift
func test_list_has_expected_elements() {
    let list = LinkedList(2, 4, 2, 3)
    XCTAssertEqual(list.map{ $0 }, [2, 4, 2, 3]) //Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected element type 'Array<(some IteratorProtocol).Element>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka '(some IteratorProtocol).Element')
}
```

After changing the `Sequence` conformance from opaque type to `LinkedListIterator<T>` it compiles without errors, however it imposes `LinkedListIterator` implementation to be `public` what is not desired.

```swift
extension LinkedList: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> LinkedListIterator<T> {
        LinkedListIterator(head: head)
    }
}
```

**How to change the implementation to use the `opaque` type and have the `Sequence` API available?**

Here is full implementation of my LinkedList:

```swift
public class LinkedList<T> {
    
    var head: Node<T>?
    
    init(_ elements : T...) {
        if let first = elements.first {
            var last = Node(data: first)
            head = last
            elements.dropFirst(1).forEach { element in
                let next = Node(data: element)
                last.next = next
                last = next
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func append(data: T) {
        let newNode = Node(data: data)
        if let last {
            last.next = newNode
        } else {
            head = newNode
        }
    }
    
    public var count: UInt {
        var runner = head
        var count: UInt = 0
        while let node = runner {
            count += 1
            runner = node.next
        }
        return count
    }
    
    private var last: Node<T>? {
        if var runner = head {
            while let next = runner.next {
                runner = next
            }
            return runner
        }
        return nil
    }
}


@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, tvOS 13.0, *)
extension LinkedList: Sequence {
    /*
    public func makeIterator() -> LinkedListIterator<T> {
        LinkedListIterator(head: head)
    }
    */
    
    public func makeIterator() -> some IteratorProtocol {
        LinkedListIterator(head: head)
    }
}

public struct LinkedListIterator<T>: IteratorProtocol {
    
    private var currentNode: Node<T>?
    
    init(head: Node<T>? = nil) {
        self.currentNode = head
    }
    
    public mutating func next() -> T? {
        if let node = currentNode {
            currentNode = node.next
            return node.data
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Swift details:
swift-driver version: 1.62.15 Apple Swift version 5.7.1 (swiftlang-5.7.1.135.3 clang-1400.0.29.51)

Comment: Why hide LinkedListIterator behind an opaque type? That's not doing any work here. Creating the type LinkedListIterator already makes it "opaque" in the useful sense that its internal details are hidden. The point of `some` is to make it easy to create *anonymous* opaque types using composable pieces without having to hand-write something like LinkedListIterator. If you're already making LinkedListIterator (which is often still useful), you don't need to also use `some`.

Comment: @RobNapier I want to keep LinkedListIterator internal in my library because it does not bring any value for the outside world. I just want to conform to the `Sequence` protocol. If I return `LinkedListIterator<T>`, Swift automatically requires to make it `public`, because `public func makeIterator()` is also public. The method signature can not be declared internal or private as it stops compiling with the following error: *Method 'makeIterator()' must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol 'Sequence'.*

Comment: I wouldn't use this here, but even so it is a supported use case. I can't remember which version of Swift does or will have it. I'm pretty certain it's not available in 5.7.1 (so the literal answer to your question is "you can't"). But I do believe it's available in 5.8 (or will be very soon). Possibly 5.7.3. I'd start by just upgrading your compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a small tweak and it'll work:

```
extension LinkedList: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> some IteratorProtocol<T> {
        LinkedListIterator(head: head)
    }
}
```

Without specializing IteratorProtocol on T the compiler will think its Element is Any (i.e. some opaque iterator type with any element type).

Comment: The answer is right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will get error even with:

```
XCTAssertEqual(list.map{ $0 }, list.map{ $0 })
```

It's problem of `opaque` types, that you know nothing about it's `associatedtype` type.
So better to return exact type if you can.
Opaque types just needed when you have monstrous generics in the result.